# Are my flags helpful?

Tags: discussion, flagging, flags

I was looking at the posts I flagged on AskUbuntu to see whether my flags were helpful or not. I saw that all my flags were accepted but two:

1. A flag on a [question about computer science](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230713/learning-about-ubuntu-partition) which has nothing to do with Ubuntu. The flag was *disputed*, but the question closed.
2. A flag on a [question about where the OP was asking how to install Windows 7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/227911/on-12-04-xp-dual-boot-system-howto-change-xp-to-win-7). The flag was neither disputed nor accepted, and the question is still open.

I'm asking this question here because, unfortunately, the Stack Exchange platform lacks ways to share feedback -- and feedback is essential to me for improving and measuring how helpful my actions are.

I would also like to know if, in general, flagging posts is useful or if you (moderators) prefer to review posts yourselves.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your flagging is helpful (as it currently stands).

There was one disputed flag - a disputed flag happens when a 10K user goes through, and disagrees with it. However, I also noticed that you only have 5 flags total, so this isn't a very large sample to judge anything by.